# finding the MGF of $-X$ given the MGF of $X$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation, moment-generating-functions

Given the following MGF for an rv $X$ on the interval $-1 < t < 1$:

$$M_X(t) = \frac{e^{t+1} - 1}{(t+1)(e-1)}$$

Determine the MGF of $Y = -X$

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Questions that look cut-and-paste from a homework set are in my, and many other users opinions, unsuitable for this site. Homework questions are allowed but they should demonstrate that you want to understand the problem better rather than just have an answer to write down. Also, homework or not, a solution won't be very helpful to you if you don't understand what the question is asking. If you don't know what the question is asking for then by all means say so, but, If you do understand this, then demonstrate that understanding so you can get better help.

Comment: Hint: By definition of Moment Generating Function: $\mathsf M_X(t) = \mathsf E(e^{tX})$ and  $\mathsf M_{Y}(s) =\mathsf E(e^{sY}) $ so ...

Comment: @TrevorGunn this is my first post on the site. It was not intended to be a 'cut and paste' from a homework set. This problem was just used to re-enforce the properties of MGFs (and expectation) and make sure I was understanding those properties. Thank you for the pointer though.

Comment: @GrahamKemp with this, I am able to 'set' t = -s and would also get:
$M_y(t) = (e^{s+1}- 1) / (s+1)*(e-1)$

Comment: No. $\mathsf M_Y(s)= \mathsf M_X(-s)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
M_{-X}(t) = \operatorname{E}(e^{t(-X)}) = \operatorname{E}(e^{(-t)X}) = M_X(-t).
$$